# correct a value exceeded by a percentage

Tags: statistics, percentages

I'm doing a statistics work for school and there is a value that is 4.15% bigger than it should. In order to get the original value I use the rule of three , counting the given value as 104.15%, to get the 'corrected' 100%. The problem is that if I use the rule of three counting the given value as 100% and then trying to get the corrected value as the 95,85% (100-4.15) is doesn't throw the same result. why?

104.15%--------14.973833431

100%------------**14.37718044**

and then

100%-----------14.973833431

95.85%--------**14.35241934**

why is it not the same? thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because $\frac{100}{100+x}$ is not the same as $\frac{100-x}{100}$.